# Why is Magisk failing ctsProfile?

Tags: magisk, safety-net

Under "SafetyNet Check Success", my Magisk shows ctsProfile is not passing? Is there anyway to check on this and figure out why?

[image: Magisk failing ctsProfile]

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tutorials.html#best-practices-for-magiskhide

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MagiskHide Props Config. Install the module from the downloads section in magisk manager. The details can be found here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magiskhide-props-config-t3789228